# Eclipse on an Android Tablet?

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ide, tablet

Note: Not sure if this is the right stack, please tell if I should migrate. (Linux Stack may be the appropriate location).

I am really looking to buy an Android tablet and currently the only thing holding me back is, I want to develop on my device. Does anyone know if Eclipse can be installed on an Android tablet? If not is Eclipse working on a port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And this is the best I've seen now

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

Comment: Thank you, sir. Your belated answer actually makes me very happy. No I have a reason to purchase a tablet.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no Android port for Eclipse. Even if there was, you would still need the Java SDK to run on Android which is not possible (yet).

Comment: Thanks. You say yet, does this indicate that it [the SDK] is in the works?

Comment: I doubt it but you never know ;)

Comment: Currently one of the legal things going on is Oracle is trying to force Google to be compliant with Java standards, if that happened you could see this happen. I doubt it though.

Answer (score 0):

Its in early stages of development, but looks promising: [java-ide-droid](http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [SL4A to do scripting on android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

or use Java IDE droid to create native Android applications. It has the Eclipse compiler by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DroidDevelop. It is JavaIDEDroid-shell for more comfortable programing.

http://en.assoft.ru/droiddevelop

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.assoft.DroidDevelop